# Setting value of a iterable property of a Python COM object

Tags: python, com, pywin32, setter, ole

I am using pywin32 to automate some tasks in software that has an Automation Server technology interface (formerly OLE Automation Server).

This software comes with a somewhat detailed manual with code examples in VBA, C++ or Matlab but no Python. I have built a Python library that can do most of the functionalities built into the software but there are some parts I cannot do in Python.

I cannot change the value of a property if this property is contained in a iterable COM object.

**What I can do:**
[Documentation for Visibility property][image: 1]

```
import win32com.client
app = win32com.client.Dispatch('NAME_OF_APP')
app.Visibility = True
```

As an example, with this code, I can change the visibility parameter of the software: if it runs with or without GUI.

**What I cannot do:**
[Documentation for getting and setting current device]
[image: Documentation for getting and setting current device]

```
import win32com.client
app = win32com.client.Dispatch('NAME_OF_APP')
app.CurrentDevice(0) = 'NAME OF DEVICE'
```

I then get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call here. Maybe you meant '==' instead of '='?
```

This error makes sense to me but I cannot find a way to set any of these software properties when they come in the form of an iterable object. As soon as I have to specify an index, I don't know how to set the value.

From what I understand, in C++ we are able to change the value because of pointers but how can we achieve the same thing in Python? Is it possible or do I have to use some C++ code in parallel to my Python to run my library? I don't know anything in C++ so if I could avoid doing that, it would be good.

**What I have tried**

Of course, the 1st thing I tried was to change () to [] or {} which logically didn't work.

Then I used the Evaluate function in PyCharms to see what was hiding behind my app.CurrentDevice. I was hoping to find sub-attributes that I could then set but I don't see anything inside the object:
[Result of Evaluate on the CurrentDevice object][image: 3]

Finally, I have tried the following:

```
import win32com.client
app = win32com.client.Dispatch('NAME_OF_APP')
curr_device = app.CurrentDevice(0)
curr_device = 'NAME OF DEVICE'
```

I wanted to affect the object to a variable and then change the value but of course, this only rewrites the variable curr-device with 'NAME OF DEVICE' but loses any link to COM Object.

I feel like my questions are similar to the following unanswered question:
[How can I set the value of an indexed property of a COM object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69348391/how-can-i-set-the-value-of-an-indexed-property-of-a-com-object-in-python)

Comment: It depends heavily on the exact definition in .IDL or in a .TLB of the COM interface. For example your first image https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvFpY.png only details the read operation (although the doc mentions read & write and it apparently works).

Comment: @SimonMourier I can confirm that read and write does work with the 1st example. Where can I find .IDL/.TLB definition? I can't find anything about IDL or TLB in software automation documentation.
Thanks

Comment: If it works with python, there's probably a TLB somewhere, in a .TLB file or in a .DLL or .EXE. It should be defined somewhere under in HKCR\TypeLib. To determine the TLBID (guid), check HKCR\[NAME_OF_APP]\CLSID value then HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\[value] then TypeLib key value. Once you have it, you can open it using OleView (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/ole-com-object-viewer) from Windows SDK

Comment: @SimonMourier thanks again for you help. This is going a bit beyond my current understanding of computers so sorry if I'm asking stupid questions.
I'm not sure where I have to find this: check HKCR[NAME_OF_APP]\CLSID value.
For this, HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID[value], I found all the software's classes in the Regestry Editor. I have the type (REG_SZ) and the value for the class in which I have the problem.
Finally, how can I find the right file to open in OLEView? I have tried multiple dll without any luck (can't find .TLB in software folders).
Thanks

Comment: What you can do is run OleView from Windows SDK, and open the "Type Libraries" tree node. Then check everything you'll have in there. It could be by GUID or by your app name directly. It may show you the path of one or two (x86+x64) files like here for some example https://i.imgur.com/APNnz5v.png Once you found it, you can directly double click on the type lib tree node and Ole View will show it "decompiled". It will give precious information https://i.imgur.com/bQToN1g.png

Comment: @SimonMourier Found it, thank you! https://imgur.com/a/6RNz5ji
From what I understand from those lines, is that to set the value, I have to do: `app.CurrentDevice(0, 'NAME OF DEVICE')`. If so, I just tried it and I get: _TypeError: CurrentDevice() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given_ I don't understand why it says 3 were given when I just put 2...

Comment: These 2 lines just describe a (indexed) property set + get. VARIANT is like 'object', it can be *anything*. So, it would be "curr_device = app.CurrentDevice(0)" and then "curr_device.something = something" or "curr_device.DoSomething(...)". It depends on what type of object CurrentDevice returns. The type of object may also be described in the type lib like "IDevice" or ...

Comment: @SimonMourier Unfortunately, I cannot locate a device object in the type lib. However, I know that `app.CurrentDevice(0)` does return a string: https://imgur.com/a/C4dWEU9. And it is this string that I would like to modify. Thus if I do `curr_device.DoSomething()`, I am actually calling string methods.

Comment: Ok if you're sure the CurrentDevice is a string for read & write, then it should be app.CurrentDevice(0) = 'NAME OF DEVICE', or maybe 'app.CurrentDevice(0, 'NAME OF DEVICE'')? If it doesn't work, it's possible win32.com doesn't support that construct (setting an indexed property).

Comment: It doesn't work so I guess it is not supported. Thank you for your help, the OLE view is very interesting and very useful for my work!

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if win32com is struggling to set the property if there is an additional argument to the `put` function, which is a little surprising.

First thing to do is to use

```
app = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('NAME_OF_APP')
```

This creates a Python wrapper for the COM object (rather than just firing function calls at the object and hoping). This may in itself clear up your issue.

If not, here is a quite ugly way of working around. As you have identified, the relevant part of the type library is:

```
[id(0x00000018),propput, helpstring("property CurrentDevice")]
HRESULT CurrentDevice([in] long lAcq, [in] VARIANT pVal);
```

And you can use this to set the property at a low level.

win32com dispatch objects are a wrapper for the `PyIDispatch` object. All dispatch objects support the `Invoke` method, and you can use this to call the function yourself. NB. Since I don't have access to your COM object, I can't test, so this answer may need some tweaking (!).

[The PyIDispatch documentation](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/PyIDispatch__Invoke_meth.html)

Try:

```
import win32com.client as wc
import pythoncom

app = wc.gencache.EnsureDispatch('NAME OF APP')
app.Visibility=TRUE

newVal = wc.VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_VARIANT,'NAME OF DEVICE')

app._oleobj_.Invoke(24,0,pythoncom.INVOKE_PROPERTYPUT,0,0,newVal)
```

There are a lot of 'magic' numbers here, but basically:

- 24 = 0x00000018 in decimal: this is the Id of the property
- 0 = the LCID, the Locale Id ... I always set it to 0
- pythoncom.INVOKE_PROPERTYPUT = the type of call.
- 0 = whether you care about the return type (you probably don't = False)
- 0 = first parameter, lAcq, as in CurrentDevice(0)
- newVal = second paramter,pVal, the new device name as a VARIANT

I haven't tried this, but `pythoncom` is pretty good about converting VARIANT types, so you might not need the `VARIANT` creation, and can just use `NAME OF DEVICE` directly as the parameter.